How can I simulate the path between two defined points but also define the overall step variance?
As stated in the question. I’m wondering if it’s possible to simulate a random walk between two fixed points (always start at A and finish at B) where the variance of the difference of steps is also defined.
Example: $A=100$, $B=125$
And of the total variance of the difference of each step is 5
I suppose there is some minimum number of steps required that is a function of B-A but I’m not sure how to think about simulating this.
I briefly stumbled on Brownian Bridges but it looks like I can only define the standard deviation of the outright levels, not the incremental steps.

Isn't this exactly a Brownian Bridge?  Could you explain how it might differ?

Yes, I think I’m getting caught up on the actual implementation of simulating this. Maybe I should first sample at the midpoint like @MattF. said, then repeat at .25 and .75 of T. Happen to know of an easier way?
